# Nodemon crashes :TypeError: Cannot read property '__nodemonRestart' of null

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I use Nodemon to run my code with Node.js (VS Code IDE). I am just a beginner and need some guidance to fix this issue. Nodemon started to crash every time when there is an error in the code (I have selected autosave option in VS Code). The error is the following:

```js
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
C:\Users\bobsa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\lib\monitor\run.js:149
      if (child.__nodemonRestart) { // this flag is set right before the kill
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '__nodemonRestart' of null
```

Do I have to change '__nodemonRestart' in run.js file? I have updated nodemon with the latest version but the issue is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it happened to me also when I did update nodemon to version **2.0.1**. you might want to go back to your old. by just running this line of code `npm i -g nodemon@your.old.version`, for example `npm i -g nodemon@1.19.4` (it is just an example)

Version History

```
2.0.1........................ 11 days ago

2.0.1-alpha.3........................ 12 days ago

2.0.1-alpha.2........................ 12 days ago

2.0.1-alpha.1........................ 12 days ago

2.0.0........................ 13 days ago

1.19.4........................ 2 months ago (this one is working fine for me)

1.19.3........................ 2 months ago

1.19.2........................ 3 months ago

1.19.1........................ 6 months ago

1.19.0........................ 7 months ago

1.18.11........................ 8 months ago
```

happy coding !!!!!

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think it solved the issue :)